# ROS2 equivalent of ros::package::getPath

Tags: ros, ardent

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a ROS2 API with similar functionality to ros::package::getPath

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288501/ros2-equivalent-of-ros::package::getpath/) by [GregB](https://answers.ros.org/users/34621/gregb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2018-04-12

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-06-01**:
@GregB can you accept and answer or ask for more clarification? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The closest equivalent to what `ros::package::getPath()` returns in ROS 1 is what we call the package's "share directory", which is essentially the package's "install prefix" plus a standard (FHS based) relative path of `share/<package name>`. This is where we put the `package.xml` and where you should install architecture independent resources like images, launch files, config files, etc...

So, as an example, if your package is called `foo` and you installed to `/home/user/my_ros2_ws/install`, then the package share directory would be `/home/user/my_ros2_ws/install/share/foo`. But to get to that path you need to know (at runtime) where the package was installed to.

In ROS 2 this information is provided by the resource index:

https://github.com/ament/ament_cmake/blob/master/ament_cmake_core/doc/resource_index.md

This index is populated at compile time (rather then by crawling the filesystem at runtime as in ROS 1).

This index can be queried in various ways, but it can be used to get the installation prefix of a package (i.e. something like `/opt/ros/ardent/` or `~/my_ros2_ws/install/`), if it is installed on the system.
Once you know that you can easily add the relative share directory path to the install prefix yourself.
However, there are convenience API's in both C++ and Python to get the "share directory" of a package directly:

#### Python

API:

https://github.com/ament/ament_index/blob/d9f7f2783dedc5687a5bdaf3ce5252dce5c073c5/ament_index_python/ament_index_python/packages.py#L56-L69

Example:

```
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
# may raise PackageNotFoundError
package_share_directory = get_package_share_directory('my_package_name')
```

#### C++

API:

https://github.com/ament/ament_index/blob/d9f7f2783dedc5687a5bdaf3ce5252dce5c073c5/ament_index_cpp/include/ament_index_cpp/get_package_share_directory.hpp#L25-L33

Example:

```
#include <ament_index_cpp/get_package_share_directory.hpp>
// may throw ament_index_cpp::PackageNotFoundError exception
std::string package_share_directory = ament_index_cpp::get_package_share_directory("my_package_name");
```

#### Command-line

With the command line you can only get the package install prefix right now, but it would be simple to add the share directory as well.

Docs (only in `-h` for now):

```
% ros2 pkg prefix -h
usage: ros2 pkg prefix [-h] package_name

Output the prefix path of a package

positional arguments:
  package_name  The package name

optional arguments:
  -h, --help    show this help message and exit
```

Example:

```
% ros2 pkg prefix rclcpp
/Users/william/ros2_ws/install_debug
```

I made an issue to add the share directory to the command line tool, help welcome :)

https://github.com/ros2/ros2cli/issues/89

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2018-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 15

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lexi](https://answers.ros.org/users/69761/lexi/) on 2021-03-04**:
Is there a way to get the src directory? This method makes it so that you have to rebuild every time you update a config which kind of defeats the purpose of a config sometimes.

**Comment by [kyubot](https://answers.ros.org/users/40914/kyubot/) on 2022-07-07**:
I agree. I need the source directory of the package rather than installed package. Any ideas?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2022-07-27**:
You should never reference the src directory of another package. It is fragile and will never work on the buildfarm. Instead you should install resources from that package and reference that package's install folder.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS 2 this information is provided by the [resource index](https://github.com/ament/ament_cmake/blob/master/ament_cmake_core/doc/resource_index.md) which is populated at compile time (rather then by crawling the filesystem as in ROS 1). This index can be queried in various ways:

- Command line: `ros2 pkg prefix rclcpp`
- [Python API](https://github.com/ament/ament_index/blob/d9f7f2783dedc5687a5bdaf3ce5252dce5c073c5/ament_index_python/ament_index_python/resources.py#L22-L34):

  ```
  import ament_index_python
  ament_index_python.get_resource('package', 'rclcpp')
  ```
- [C++ API](https://github.com/ament/ament_index/blob/d9f7f2783dedc5687a5bdaf3ce5252dce5c073c5/ament_index_cpp/include/ament_index_cpp/get_resource.hpp#L27) (no example code out of my head...)

In either of the cases the result is the prefix path where the specific package is being installed. Depending on that information you are looking for you can construct derived paths manually. E.g. the manifest is in the location `<prefix>/share/<pkgname>`, the include directory is in `<prefix>/include` etc.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-04-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-04-12**:
The exact equivalent in Python is this function:

https://github.com/ament/ament_index/blob/d9f7f2783dedc5687a5bdaf3ce5252dce5c073c5/ament_index_python/ament_index_python/packages.py#L56-L69

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-04-12**:
Sorry, that was the wrong one for Python, I'll edit the comment. The C++ one is here: https://github.com/ament/ament_index/blob/d9f7f2783dedc5687a5bdaf3ce5252dce5c073c5/ament_index_cpp/include/ament_index_cpp/get_package_share_directory.hpp#L25-L33

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-04-12**:
Both of those are to the share directory of the package (which is the closest thing in my opinion to `ros::package::getPath`), both also have the "installation prefix for a package" and the ability to list packages and their prefixes.

**Comment by [mkhansen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25277/mkhansen/) on 2018-06-01**:
I'm using ament_index_cpp::get_package_prefix("packagename"), which returns the same as 'ros2 pkg prefix '. Is there any reason why that isn't the recommended answer to this question?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-06-01**:
@mkhansen, do you mean why is this not the example in this answer or why is it not the answer to the original question? I would say `ament_index_cpp::get_package_prefix()` isn't the closest replacement for `ros::package::getPath`, but I explain that in my answer above.

**Comment by [mkhansen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25277/mkhansen/) on 2018-06-04**:
@william - OK, I see the difference now. I was thinking getPath() was for the prefix, not the share location.